# Database table design - are my fields correct?

Tags: mysql

I need to sell items on my fictitious website and as such have come up with a couple of tables and was wondering if anyone could let me know if this is plausible and if not where i might be able to change things?

I am thinking along the lines of;

Products table : ID, Name, Cost, mediaType(FK)

Media: Id, Name(book, cd, dvd etc)

What is confusing me is that a user might have / own many products, but how would you store an array of product id's in a single column?

Thanks

Comment: just thought, maybe i could actually have a purchases table, with a user id and product id?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't store an array of things into a single column. In fact you usually wouldn't store them in *separate* columns either.

You need to step away from design for a bit and go investigate third normal form. That should be you starting point and, in  the vast majority of cases, your ending point for designing database schemas.

The correct way of handling variable size "arrays" is with two tables with a many to one relationship, something like:

```
Users
    User ID (primary key)
    Name
    Other user info
Objects:
    Object Id (primary key)
    User id (foreign key, references Users(User id)
    Other object info
```

That's the simplest form where one object is tied to a specific user, but a specific user may have any number of objects.

Where an object can be "owned" by multiple users (I say an object meaning (for example) the book "Death of a Salesman", but obviously each user has their own *copy* of an object), you use a joining table:

```
Users
    User ID (primary key)
    Name
    Other user info
Objects:
    Object Id (primary key)
    User id (foreign key, references Users(User id))
    Other object info
UserObjects:
    User id (foreign key, references Users(User id))
    Object id (foreign key, references Objects(Object id))
    Count
    primary key (User id, Object id)
```

Similarly, you can handle one or more by adding an object id to the Users table.

But, until you've nutted out the simplest form and understand 3NF, they won't generally matter to you.

Answer (score 0):

> What is confusing me is that a user might have / own many products, but how would you store an array of product id's in a single column?

This is called a "many-to-many" relationship. In essence you would have a table for users, a table for products, and a table to map them like this:

```
[table] Users
   - id
   - name
[table] Products
   - id
   - name
   - price
[table] Users_Products
   - user_id
   - product_id
```

Then when you want to know what products a user has, you could perform a query like:

```
SELECT product_id FROM Users_Products WHERE user_id=23;
```

Of course, user id 23 is fictituous for examples sake. The resulting recordset would contain the id's of all the products the user owns.

Comment: yes - i just thought of this exact example on paper but had it down as purchase table!

Comment: That's a many-to-many, by the way, not one-to-many. For a one-to-many, you don't need a separate joining table since a given product can only belong to one user.

Answer (score 0):

You could something like store a JSON array in a text or varchar field and let the application handle parsing it.

MySQL doesn't have a native array type, unlike say PostgreSQL, but in general I find if you're trying to store an array you're probably doing something wrong. Of course every rule has its exceptions.

What your probably want is a user table and then a table that correlates products to users. If a product is only going to relate to one user then you can add a user ID column to your Products table. If not, then you'll want another lookup table which handles the many to many relationship. It would look something like this:

```
------------------------
| user_id | product_id |
------------------------
|       1 |          1 |
|       1 |          2 |
|       1 |          3 |
|       2 |          2 |
|       3 |          1 |
|       3 |          5 |
------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one way of storing all the products which user has in one column is to store it as a string where product ids are separated by some delimiters like comma. Though this is not the way you want to solve. The best way to solve this problem would be to have a seperate user table and than have a user product table where you associate userid with product id. You could than simple use a simple query to get list of all the products owned by a particular userid

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, try to think of the system in terms of the major parts - you would have a 'warehouse', so you need a table to list the products you have, and you are going to possibly have users who register their details with you for regular visits - so an account per user. You would generally hold all details of a single product in the same row of the same table (unless you have a really complex product to detail, but not likely). If you're going to keep track of products bought per user account, there's always the option of keeping the order history as a delimited list in a large text field. For example: date,id,id,id,id;date,id,id. Or you could simply refer to order numbers and have a separate table for orders placed [by any customer].